# Play audio from remote machine to local machine's speaker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, audio

Most of the time I used to run long-running jobs/build on Linux machines (locally and remote). I wish if there is an audible alert when a command is completed. It turns out there is [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277215/how-to-make-a-sound-once-a-process-is-complete) which works locally.

```
make; spd-say Done
```

or

```
./a.out ; spd-say Done
```

Can I do the same on an SSH session to the remote server machine? Just like we `-X` for display. Is there anything like that for tunnelling the audio back to the local machine?

The following is my workflow on the remote server.

1. `ssh user@remote`
2. `cd /some/folder/to/run`
3. `./runThatExecutable` or `make`
   ... I keep checking the status of completion regularly. Sometimes I forget to. Eventually, it ends.
4. Then perform the follow-up activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ssh remote-host make; spd-say Done
```

Only the `make` command executes remotely.  When it finishes, `spd-say` will execute locally.

For cases where you have a more complex command to run than a simple `make`, you can either replace `make` in the command above with the (suitably quoted and escaped) command list you want to run:

```
ssh remote-host 'cd /some/folder/to/run; ./runThatExecutable'; \
    spd-say Done
```

In more complex cases, you may want to create a script on the remote host and then invoke that script:

```
ssh remote-host 'cd /some/folder/to/run; ./runThatScript.sh'; \
    spd-say Done
```

Comment: Thanks Jm, This run make in $HOME? How do we make it run from specific folder?

Comment: @mrprajesh At the simplest level, it might just be `make -C /path/to/directory`.  If you're doing something more complex than that, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/682920/edit) your post to show the actual steps you're using instead of just `make` and I'll try to incorporate that into my answer.

Comment: Sure. Thanks, Jim. I have marked it accepted. I have also edited as requested. Because most of the time it is not a `make` but some other executable.